# How to compile C code in run time and use it's Functions

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio-2010

Let's say I have C# program and I will take a foo.c file as input at the beginning.

Is it possible to use functions in foo.c  file in my C# program ?If possible, How can I do that?

EDIT : This is an example what I want to do

in C# part:

```
int main()
{

string filePath = "SampleCode.c";
string SourceCode = File.ReadAllText("SampleCode.c");

//I want to some how compile this source code here

                          ***
function1();
function2();

}
```

in SampleCode.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>

function1()
{
...
}

function2()
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Compile the file.
2. Link it into a DLL.
3. Load the DLL.
4. Call the functions in the DLL.

Comment: Can you tell me how to compile this file and link it into a DLL  dynamically ?

Comment: It depends what compiler you want to use. Pick a compiler and check its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

C needs to be compiled then referenced and the something like the below articles can show you how to call it from C#.

[Example of calling C/C++ code from C# when location is not known until run time.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.net-_2800_c_23002900_.aspx)

[Example of calling C functions from within C#](http://www.moythreads.com/wordpress/2008/02/04/pinvoke-how-to-call-c-from-c/)

[PDF examples of C library calls from C#](http://www.nag.com/IndustryArticles/Calling_C_Library_DLLs_from_C_Sharp.pdf)